# Is it possible to use authenticatedUserOverride in IIS and still get the windows user within an MVC application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, acl

We're trying to setup IIS so that is uses its IIS AppPool identity when going against ACL permission checks (when getting static files from the filesystem) so that we don't have to add "everyone" or "authenticated" users to the main app folder or specific folders.

We've found that setting `authenticatedUserOverride` to `UserWorkerProcessUser` achieves the above, but no longer lets us access the specific windows user hitting the website from within the MVC application.

Is there a better way to accomplish this? Again, we're trying avoid having the specific user's credentials validated against ACLs when accessing files.

Comment: Have you tried using a service account like NetworkService or LocalService as the Identity instead of the AppPoolIdentity?

Answer (score 2):

You can still get the authenticated user that is accessing the site using the LOGON_USER in the Request:

```
Request["LOGON_USER"]
```

Scott Forsyth details this on his blog under option #4 (http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/iis-using-windows-authentication-with-minimal-permissions-granted-to-disk).

As for the best way to accomplish this, I think you are on the right path.  I have used this approach along with the roles authorization aspect of ASP.NET to allow/deny access based on membership.